# Search in Elastic Search with AND operator

Tags: elasticsearch

I have the following documents in my ES

```
  name                 type
Thomas Robert King     xyz
Peter  Jacob  Junior   xyz
Robert Einstein Jr     abc
Thomas Jupyin   DR     xyz
```

I want to get all the documents where it matches for Robert and Thomas both in a sentence and are of type xyz.

The current ES query that i have created is :

```
http://localhost/index/type/_search/?size=100&pretty=1/
{
"query": {
"bool": {
"must": [
{
"match":
{ "name": "Thomas" }
},
{
"match":
{ "name": "Robert" }
}
],
"must_not": [
{
{
"match":
{ "type": "abc" }
}
]
}
}
}
```

Is it the right way to create a AND scenario in elastic search or is there a better query to handle the same output .
I am using ES 2.1
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given your current goal: get all the documents where it matches for Robert and Thomas both in a sentence and are of type xyz, you should not use a must_not query on abc. If there is another type ( ubv for example), your query will also get the documents which match this type.

You can do that query:

```
{
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "must": [
            {
                "match":
                { 
                      "name": {
                          "query": "Thomas Robert",
                          "operator": "and" 
                      }
                }
            },
            {
               "match":
               { 
                     "type": "xyz" 
               }
            }
         ]
      }
   }
}
```

By the way, the clauses must are scoring query in a bool query. If you want just want to filter on type xyz you should use:

```
{
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "must": [
            {
                "match":
                { 
                      "name": {
                          "query": "Thomas Robert",
                          "operator": "and" 
                      }
                }
            }],
            "filter": [
                 {
                     "match": 
                     {
                         "type": "xyz"
                     }
                 }
            ]
      }
   }
}
```

Moreover please look at term level query versus full-text query, to see what you really need. If your "type" field is not analyzed, you should use term query instead of match to avoid analysis in match query.

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/2.3/term-level-queries.html

Comment: the second query says its a invalid json because of some parenthesis missing ,could you let me know what i am missing